# opentsdb api/query downsample result is incorrect

Tags: opentsdb

I used API/query downsample to query the data, but the results I get are different. I cannot explain why.

My first query:

```
    {
        "start": 1498838400,
        "end": 1501516800,
        "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "useCalendar": true,
        "delete": false,
        "queries": [
            {
                "aggregator": "sum",
                "metric": "meter.energy.active.forward.z",
                "downsample": "24h-first",
                "rate": false,
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "type": "literal_or",
                        "tagk": "deviceId",
                        "filter": "127",
                        "groupBy": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

The result:

```
    [{
       "metric": "meter.energy.active.forward.z",
       "tags":    {
          "deviceTypeId": "1",
          "deviceNo": "340340001750",
          "deviceId": "127",
          "gatewayId": "72"
       },
       "aggregateTags": [],
       "dps":    {
          "1498924800": 0.029999999329447746,
          "1499097600": 349577.59375,
          "1499184000": 410578.90625,
          "1499270400": 515834.09375,
          "1499356800": 616553.6875,
          "1499443200": 722792.5,
          "1499529600": 800983.75...}}]
```

For the second request, I only change 24h-first to 24h-first-nan, and the second request result is:

```
    [{
       "metric": "meter.energy.active.forward.z",
       "tags":    {
          "deviceTypeId": "1",
          "deviceNo": "340340001750",
          "deviceId": "127",
          "gatewayId": "72"
       },
       "aggregateTags": [],
       "dps": {}
    }]
```

I want the result is:

```
[{
           "metric": "meter.energy.active.forward.z",
           "tags":    {
              "deviceTypeId": "1",
              "deviceNo": "340340001750",
              "deviceId": "127",
              "gatewayId": "72"
           },
           "aggregateTags": [],
           "dps":    {
              "1498924800": 0.029999999329447746,
              "1499011200": NaN,
              "1499097600": 349577.59375,
              "1499184000": 410578.90625,
              "1499270400": 515834.09375,
              "1499356800": 616553.6875,
              "1499443200": 722792.5,
              "1499529600": 800983.75...}}]
```

I also delete the "useCalendar", but the time is not what I want.

Do you see my issue? Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: Tried to make more obvious where the problem lies.

Comment: Please add an example of what you would expect as a correct result.

Comment: Please edit your original question, not the comments ;-)